# Problems using "Kblocks" package for drawing "Block diagrams"

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, graphs, signal-processing

**My first question is:**
How to move or shift the label on a given link like in the attached photo?

**My second question is:**
How to bend the link to become a 90 deg as shown in the picture?
I attached my code in `tex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kblocks}

\begin{document}
\begin{kblock}
\kStartNodec[$V_1$]{(0,-1.5)}{R1}
\kScaleDistX[1.5]
\kPlusMinusDown{R1}{S1}{0cm}
\kLink[]{R1}{S1}
\kInDown[]{S1}{um}{${V}_{4}$}{0}
\kScaleDistX[1.5]
\kTFRight{S1}{C1}{$0.35$}
\kLink[]{S1}{C1}
\kScaleDistX[3.46]
\kPlusPlusUp{C1}{S2}{1cm}
\kLink []{C1}{S2}
\kStartNodec[]{(0,1)}{R2}
\kScaleDistX[1.5]
\kPlusPlusahm{R2}{S3}{0cm}
\kInUp[]{S3}{um}{$V_2$}{0}
\kInDown[]{S3}{um}{$V_3$}{0}
\kTFRight{S3}{C2}{$\frac{1}{2}$}
\kLink[]{S3}{C2}
\kStartNodec[$I^\ast$]{(0,3)}{R5}
\kScaleDistX[3]
\kPlusMinusDown{R5}{S5}{0cm}
\kLink[]{R5}{S5}
\kLink[$I_{{calculated}}$]{C2}{S5}
\kScaleDistX[1]
\kTFRight{S5}{C3}{$s$}
\kLink[]{S5}{C3}
\kMinusPlusUp{C3}{S6}{0.2cm}
\kLink[]{C3}{S6}
\kInUp[]{S6}{um}{${V}_{dc}$}{0}
\kTFRight{S6}{C7}{$0.2$}
\kLink[]{S6}{C7}
\kTFRight{C7}{C8}{$K_3$}
\kLink[]{C7}{C8}
\kLink[$V_{estimated.}$]{C8}{S2}
\kOutRight{S2}{Y1}{$V_{out}^\ast$}{0cm}
\end{kblock}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The kblocks pacakge has been updated. However, it might take a while for the code changes to reflect on the package arvhive. You can, however, download it from
https://github.com/somefunAgba/kblocks

Here is probably the diagram that you want to realize

```
\begin{kblock}
% ref
\kJumpCS{spt}
% top blocks
\kMarkNodeRight{0cm}{0cm}{$I^\star$}{spt}{inI}
\kPlusMinusDown{inI}{sb1}{1.cm}
\kTFRight[0.2cm]{sb1}{tfb1}{$s$}
\kTFBelow[0.5cm]{sb1}{tfb2}{$\frac{1}{2}$}  
\kPlusDownPlusUpL{tfb2}{sb2}{0cm}
\kMinusPlusUp{tfb1}{sb3}{0cm}
\kTFRight[0cm]{sb3}{tfb3}{$0.2$}
\kTFRight[0cm]{tfb3}{tfb4}{$K_3$}
\kMarkNodeAbove{0cm}{0cm}{$V_{dc}$}{inI}{inVdc}
\kMarkNodeBelow{0cm}{0.3cm}{$V_2$}{inI}{inV2}
\kMarkNodeBelow{0cm}{-0.4cm}{$V_3$}{inV2}{inV3}
% bottom blocks
\kMarkNodeBelow{3cm}{0cm}{$V_1$}{inI}{inV1}
\kPlusPlusUpB{tfb4}{sb4}{3cm}
\kPlusMinusDown{inV1}{sb5}{0cm}
\kTFRight[0cm]{sb5}{tfb5}{$0.35$}
\kOutRight[0]{sb4}{outV}{$V_{out}^{\star}$}{0}
\kMarkNodeBelow{0cm}{0cm}{$V_4$}{inV1}{inV4}
% top links
\kLinkHV[]{inVdc}{sb3}{0}{0}{0}
\kLinkHV[]{inV2}{sb2}{0}{0}{0}
\kLinkHV[]{inV3}{sb2}{0}{0}{0}
\kLink[]{inI}{sb1}
\kLink[]{sb1}{tfb1}
\kLink[$I_{calc}$]{tfb2}{sb1}
\kLink[]{tfb1}{sb3}
\kLink[]{sb2}{tfb2}
\kLink[]{sb3}{tfb3}
\kLink[]{tfb3}{tfb4}
\kLink[$V_{est}$]{tfb4}{sb4}
% bottom links
\kLink[]{inV1}{sb5}
\kLink[]{sb5}{tfb5}
\kLink[]{tfb5}{sb4}
\kLinkHV[]{inV4}{sb5}{0}{0}{0}
\end{kblock}
```

Comment: Thanks very much 
engineer Oluwasegun Somefun
Your Kblock package is one of the easiest packages out there for drawing block diagrams 
I urge all of the newbies like myself to start using it

Comment: @ahmadalaa Thank you for the positive usecase comments.